# Converting Pdo OOP To Mysqli Procedural

Tags: authentication

Folks, :)

My 3+ pages are all in mysqli procedural. I cannot just switch to pdo and oop and throw 6 mnths of work down the drain! And so, let's try converting the following code suggestion by another to mysqli procedural.
I really need the following code converted to mysqli procedural from pdo oop. Once that is done, my 7 months project will come to an end. And, I can move-on to learning pdo. Right now, can't afford to jump into pdo without finishing my current project.
So, who will help me convert ? Other newbies would learn from your conversion.

Thanks!

[code]

```
/*
ERROR HANDLING
*/
declare(strict_types=1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

include 'config.php';

// check if user is already logged in
if (is_logged() === true) 
{
    //Redirect user to homepage page after 5 seconds.
    header("refresh:2;url=home.php");
    exit; //
}

if (
    array_key_exists('login_username_or_email', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('login_password' , $_POST)
) {
    $usernameoremail = trim($_POST["login_username_or_email"]); //
    $password = $_POST["login_password"];

    // don't bother trimming, they can't enter it right, don't let them log 
in!

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ids, usernames, passwords, emails, 
accounts_activations_statuses
    FROM users WHERE ' . (
        strpos($usernameoremail, '@') === false) ? 'usernames' : 'emails'
    ) . ' = ?
    ');

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['login_username_or_email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result(
        $db_id, $db_username, $db_password, $db_email,
        $db_account_activation_status
    );

    if (
        $stmt->fetch() &&
        password_verify($_POST['login_password'], $db_password)
    ) {
        echo '
            <p>Login Successful</p>
            <dl>
                <dt>User Id</dt>
                <dd>', $db_id, '</dd>
                <dt>E-Mail</dt>
                <dd>', $db_email, '</dd>
                <dt>Username</dt>
                <dd>', $db_username, '</dd>
                <dt>Activation Stats</dt>
                <dd>', $db_account_activation_status, '</dd>
            </dl>
        ';
    } else echo '<p>Invalid username or password</p>';

    $stmt->close();

} else echo '<p>Missing username or password</p>';



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php $site_name?> Member Login Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
<form method="post" action="">
    <h3><?= $site_name ?> Member Login Form</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="login_name">Username/Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="login_username_or_email" id="login_name">
        <br>
        <label for="login_pass">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_pass">
    </fieldset>
    <div class="submitsAndHiddens">
        <button type="submit">Login</button><br>
        <a href="login_password_reset.php">Forgot your Password?</a><br>
        <a href="register.php">Register New Account</a>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

[/code]